# hta: Changing font size issue using css

Tags: html, css, hta

I have an HTA file, I put some buttons and a comboBox
When I added some text to say what to select, it was too big.
I tried to change the size in CSS

```
<body style="font-size: 10px;">
```

It didn't work.
Also tried

```
<body size="10">
```

Nothing worked, so I decided to ask here for help

I got results using span

```
<span style="font-size: 10px;"> Select office </span>
```

But I want a much elegant situation and easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use points instead.

```
html, body{
 font-size:10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an external style or an internal style like,

```
html, body {
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

It applies the style throughout the body.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to put your css in a separate file, it makes the code mach more understandable and prevents you from writing code twice.
2. Check for a  without closure
3. If this doesn't work try sending us sum more code